# How to type asterisk while being in screen

Tags: linux, terminal

How to type asterisk (*) character while running "screen" in terminal? Asterisk is binded to show a listing of all currently attached displays. Maybe there is some way to unbind it?

Comment: Have you overridden the key bindings for screen (I think screen has a .screenrc or something)? Normally, control-a " is used to see a list do listing of displays in the screen implementations I've used.

Comment: I didn't override anything. I see this behavior on all systems, with fresh "screen" install. Cannot type *, screen just flickers and nothing happens.

Comment: My `Screen version 4.00.03jw4 (FAU) 2-May-06` on Ubuntu 13.04 allows me to type `*`. It only shows the displays when I do `^A *`.

Comment: What OS? What version of screen? What is $TERM? I use Ubuntu 12.04 and screen 4.00.03jw4 as well.

Comment: Debian 7, `Screen version 4.01.00devel (GNU) 2-May-06`, $TERM=xterm

Comment: Same behavior on CentOS release 6.5 (Final), `Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06`. In all cases I use ssh.